# Toggle vs pivot vs what else?

Tags: c#, uwp

I have an Observable collection bound to a gridview in UWP. The grid view indicates the location of the warehouse that an item can be stored in row column form. A1 B7 C13 etc.

I have heard that there are now two warehouses and shipment items can be spread over more than one warehouse for a single shipment.

The suggested solution was to use a toggle control to toggle between warehouse1 and warehouse2, but how will I go about updating the gridview and its observable collection (The warehouseID is stored in the observable collection, but should I just filter the observable collection items based on toggleON or ToggleOFf?
 should the toggle control itself be bound to something? should I use a pivot control instead,

what are my possibilities for this type of problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Method 1:

Use [`AdvancedCollectionView`](http://www.uwpcommunitytoolkit.com/en/master/helpers/AdvancedCollectionView/) to filter the `ObservableCollection`

Sample code: (Source: [AdvancedCollectionView](http://www.uwpcommunitytoolkit.com/en/master/helpers/AdvancedCollectionView/))

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

var oc = new ObservableCollection<Person>
{
    new Person { Name = "Staff" },
    new Person { Name = "42" },
    ......
    ......
};

var acv = new AdvancedCollectionView(oc);
int nul;
acv.Filter = x => !int.TryParse(((Person)x).Name, out nul); 
YourGridView.ItemsSource = acv;
```

### Method 2:

Use two `ObservableCollection` one is for ToggleON and another is for ToggleOFF. Change the `GridView.ItemsSource` corresponding to `ToggleButton` (OR) Use `Pivot`.